# How to get the maximum lenght of a column in excel using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am working on a project which involves reading excel data using Apache POI. 
I have a situation  where I have to  find out the maximum length of a column.

**For example**
A sheet has 3 rows r1, r2, r3 and 2  columns c1 and c2 and all contains string data. Now say  string size in r1c1 is  5, in r2c1 is 6 and in r3c1 is 7.

Is there any method available in Apache POI such that

`foo(c1)` will return 7.

Currently I am using foo loop to iterate over all the cells in the column and calculate the maximum size, however it is hitting the performance as excel file is large.

I went through the documentation but can't find one. Is for loop only way to do it?

**Why I want this**

I have to write a functionality where application can upload excel in db. DDL statement should be created on the fly and to generate ddl statement, I need to know the max length of column. I know I am trying to reinvent  the wheel as db like MySQL already has this plugin, but here I am not suppose to use that because I want to keep everything in one place. I went through the source code of plugin but it is too complex to copy in the project.

Comment: You want to find the length of a cell or maximum length of the all columns is a row/Sheet ? Why can't you simply use "cell.ToString().Length" ?

Comment: in my example c1 can have different maximum length  than c2. So `foo(c1)` will return max length of c1 and `foo(c2)` will return max length of c2.

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan, that will return length of that cell only, not the max length of column.

Comment: Yes, it does not. That's why I asked what you want to get! Now I see what you are asking. I don't think there is a method which does that. You may want to loop through the cells. However, I am curious why would you want that. Do you have a specific Context ?

Comment: @PrageethSaravanan If he, as me, has an excel file of 1000s of rows to be uploaded into a database, he wouldn't want to first parse the whole file to get this information and then build the database schema corresponding (varchar(X) is an issue here) and parsing a second time while uploading row after row but rather getting the information first without parsing everything, then building the schema and uploading during the first parsing line after line.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can solve it using [getColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getColumnWidth(int)) : If your maximum length in a column always match the width of the column (no useless space except for the left and right margins), you might be able to "guess" the maximum length only using the column width and dividing it by the length 1 character is supposed to have (IF they all have the same length). But even if it possible you might need to consider the margins + the tiny space between two characters in the calculation.

With a general and very simple exemple : if your column is 10 units and you know that one character have a length of 1 unit, then you know that the maximum string has 10 characters.

This is very very theoric as I cannot code anything right now, but this is the only solution I can imagine besides what you have already done.